# Best way to import/export a Apache Jackrabbit repository

Tags: apache, import, export, repository, jackrabbit

What is the best way to import/export data from a Apache Jackrabbit repository?

Right now, I have a website based on a repository with over 100GB data in a server but I frequently need to take a subset of this data in my notebook for in-loco demonstrations.

How can I do this in the easiest and fastest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for it my best bet is this tool:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/sandbox/jackrabbit-jcr-import-export-tool/README.txt

But, judging solely from the README file, it doesn't look very reliable.

The other problem is that it requires me to know the file names of all files I want to export in advance, which would be bothersome, since my main criteria for extraction is to copy the most recent files, ie, using the creation date as the filter.

The ideal solution would let me browse through the files in the repository as in a regular file-system and use simple copy tools to extract the data.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there aren't that many generic JCR tools. Sling has two jcr explorers, one that is GWT based and another JS-based, but neither export.

Comment: There is also a more modern and new explorer written in JQueryMobile + Spring on the backend: http://meta64.com (Full disclosure: I wrote it!)

Answer (score 1):

There is CRX from Day, but it costs some money

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into this myself. Would Session.exportSystemView() and Session.importXML() work? Those will apparently allow you to serialize/deserialize a subtree as XML.